# Best route to take when replacing an old panel without a main breaker

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a severely scary Stab-Lok panel that has no main breaker. The breakers spark and fall out when the panel is slightly wiggled. It's tiny and there's hardly any room to work, so I'm not about to screw around inside there while the mains are live. So, I need to have the electric company come out and pull the meter.

I figure while the meter is off, why not just replace the panel? So I bought a 200A load center with main breaker installed. My service is currently only 100A, but we plan on upgrading some time in the future (not sure how long it'll be). The main concern right now is to get the damned Stab-Lok panel out of here.

So, the question I have is, which is the best temporary route to take?

1. Just connect the lines to the installed 200A main breaker.
2. Remove the breaker and convert panel to main lug and connect directly (as the old one is now).
3. Remove the installed breaker. And backfeed the panel through 100A breaker as specified in the wiring diagram. (But lose 4 spaces.)

Honestly, I'm strongly leaning towards #1. At least the panel will be protected and I'll be able to use the main breaker as a disconnect.

Thanks,
Michael

BTW, the panel I bought was a Siemens P3040B1200CU and they don't make a 100A main breaker for it.

Update with photo:
[image]

The Siemens panel I plan to use photo:
[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Good question; keep 'em coming! (And, a picture of the scary panel would be fun, and perhaps informative.)

Comment: When you say your panel has "no main breaker", are you talking about a Rule of Six panel, with a breaker in the "top half" feeding the breakers in the "bottom half"?

Comment: Also, do you have a full 14" between studs available for the new panel? The word "tiny" has me concerned that your new panel may not *fit* where you're trying to put it...

Comment: Finally, photos of the old main panel would be helpful here :)

Comment: All spaces are filled and being used for lines through the house. There isn't a backfed breaker feeding the stems. The main lines connect directly to the panel lugs.  It's an old house, the panel is in the basement, there are no "walls" just the foundation. There's plenty of room for the new panel as there are no studs to speak of, just stone - it's an old house. The old panel is attached directly to the stone walls. I'm making a frame for the new panel and will attach it to the joists above and anchor it to the wall at the bottom.

Comment: @Michael -- we'll *definitely* need photos to judge what the deal is with the old panel then

Comment: Out side at meter is there a shutoff ?

Comment: @Michael -- why the frame? surface mounting a panel to a wall is an A-OK thing to do (and in fact quite common in spaces that aren't held to a high standard of finish, such as industrial plants and the like)

Comment: @Kris: Nope. No shut-off. Just a box with a meter. From what I understand, there are a lot of house in my area like this. Some people just pull the meters themselves - which I'm not about to do having never done it before.

Comment: @Michael -- is posting pictures of the old panel an issue for some reason?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: The walls in the basement tend to "weep". Haha. Not uncontrollably, but too much for me to be comfortable attaching an electrical panel to.

Comment: My power company informs me that before they will turn power back on after you have upgraded from 100 to 200 amp feed there must be an inspection of the entire electrical system. A 200 amp breaker being fed from a 100 amp service is not safe.  Is there a 100 amp breaker anywhere in the current setup?

Comment: @Kris: Nope. No 100A breaker anywhere.

Comment: @Kris -- yeah, this is a *very* small panel being used under the "rule of six" (if you count, it requires exactly six throws to turn all circuits off)

Comment: @Michael is the photo I added to your question correct?

Comment: @ Kris: Yep. That's the one I bought. (Seems like overkill, but there's a subpanel running off that 50A breaker in the main, filled with 8 more breakers -- and no ground bar!!! It has to go as well.)

Comment: A 30-space panel is never overkill.  If anything, I was thinking it's a bit small.   The reason is there are a bunch of things you haven't done because they've been out of the question because you haven't had the panel spaces.  Now that you do, believe me, you'll fill 'em up!

Answer (score 3):

1) can't happen without the power company's consent, and the meter pan and service drop up to the weatherhead must also be rated for 200A.   If those aren't true, you can't do #1.

2) is out of the question.  The old setup was legal because it was so small it qualified for the Rule of Six (six throws to turn off everything).  And the  maximum theoretical load, all circuits at redline, was 125A on one pole and 150A on the other. That is *such a modest* oversubscription that *since the Rule of Six was allowed*, a main breaker wasn't really needed.   However, different deal on a modern 30-42 space panel with 200-400A of breakers provisioned on each pole. Besides, the Rule of Six is now outlawed! **You must have a main breaker today**.

That leaves #3, and I recommend switching panel brands to one where a 100A main breaker is readily available.  Unless you plan to have a generator; in that case stay with Siemens but swap it out to a main-lug panel (why pay for the main breaker) and fit their generator interlock.

You can also backfeed this panel and ignore the main breaker, but I do not like panels where the main shutoff is not *obvious*.  In an emergency, people don't rise to the occasion, they sink to the level of their training.  In other words people get stupid in key moments.  Someone frantically working in the dark is gonna grab the big handle and go THWOP.  And he will expect the power to be off at that point.  So if that does *nothing* and you have to shut off one of the regular breakers, well, that's just confusing...

Comment: As I mentioned this is only temporary, so I’m not too worried about someone else messing with the panel. I did decide on #3 though and leaving the main breaker in place. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

### I would go with option #3, but leave the 200A main fitted

Personally, given your situation, I would go with option #3; you only actually lose *two* spaces (instead of the four you think you do) by doing this, and you get properly sized protection as a result. (The lack of downbreaker kits for 200A panels is a major downside of the Siemens loadcenter line, I find, even.)

However, you can leave the panel in its *main breaker* configuration even though you are fitting a backfed main.  This saves you the time and cost of fitting a main lug kit and matching filler plate to your replacement panel, and the unused breaker is not an issue from a Code standpoint as long as it's marked on the directory as unused, with the real main marked accordingly.

Comment: I thought the main breaker was to protect the panel, not the service lines? Is it for both? Because as it is now, there's nothing!

Comment: Also... I was told it was not safe to leave the main breaker in with a backfed main? And finally, the panel will be surface mounted. when I run the studs from joist to floor, I'll put cross boards between to attach the panel to.

Comment: @Michael -- it protects the panel busbars from *overcurrents* (from any cause), as well as protecting the service lines from *overload* (but not short-circuits or gross ground-faults).  Also, there is no hazard of having the main breaker present if a backfed main is also present (otherwise generator interlock kits wouldn't fly)

Comment: So let me ask you, why does the wiring diagram state that you need to leave the opposite spaces open when using a backfed breaker?

Comment: @Michael -- it *doesn't* say that, actually

Comment: After looking at it again, you’re right. I know I read it somewhere, but can’t remember?

Comment: @michael It is often a requirement for the backfed breaker to have none opposite,  I presume stab limits might be a reason.  .

Comment: @Harper After installing a hold-down clip on that 100A breaker, it is not possible to use the spaces on the opposite side - so, I did end up losing 4 spaces. I can get by without them. When all is said and done, I believe 22 spaces will be used for 20 circuits.